# Reverse proxy setup for distributed storage

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have 4 file servers that I want to access under a single mount point from another server. This server has a web application that should serve content from the mounted point.
I think I can achieve this with glusterfs.

Considering that the file servers have fairly powerful hardware, I want to install a webserver on each of them and serve those files via a reverse proxy.

Any thoughts on how I may be able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> I have 4 file servers that I want to access under a single mount point from another server

I suspect that sentence is rather confused. Yes you can have multiple filesystems accessible and mounted at the same place - but its not a trivial exercise - I suspect your intention is to provide a gateway to the four filesystems via a single mount point - which is not the same thing at all.

Do you mean that the same filesystem is to be available on 4 servers? This is the only scenario where glusterfs would seem to make sense.

What are the protocols involved here?

Assuming that its a replication problem, how near to real time does it have to be? How should it cope with failures?

You seem to think that a reverse-proxy is a solution. But a solution to what?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realise that what I want to achieve is not simple and is susceptible failure if something goes wrong(it's not something I support either).
Your assertion is also correct, I want a gateway as a single mount point. The data needs to be served via http, but I don't want to flood the main server with requests that's why I want to serve the files from the machine that hosts them in the first place. To do so I figured I would need a reverse proxy.

Comment: If the four servers are to serve up the same files, then it would be far better to replicate the files across the servers (afs, rsync, unionfs) rather than use a common substrate. Using a reverse proxy in front of these will only slow the system down - you just need some sort of load balancing (round robin DNS is by far the most sensible way of doing this)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, I ended up using gluster fs on the servers, having a single web server on the machine that hosted the gluster client for all the hosts.